# Example of how to use String.Create in .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core

Does anyone know how this method is intended to be used? The documentation is somewhat 'light'!

```
public static string Create<TState> (int length, TState state, System.Buffers.SpanAction<char,TState> action);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.create?view=netcore-2.2

Comment: A quick search on String.Create found [this MSDN artcie, which includes an example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Ha! I've read that document and totally forgot it was in there... Thanks!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The [`String.Create()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.create?view=netstandard-2.1) needs three things:

1. The final `length` of the string. You must know this in advance, because the method needs it to *safely* create an internal fixed-length buffer for the `Span<char>` instance used to construct the final string.
2. The  data (`state`) which will become your string. For example, you might have an array buffer (of, say, ascii integers received over the network), but it could be *anything*. This is the raw data that will be transformed into the final string. There is an example buried deep in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that even uses a `Random` instance. I've also seen an incomplete example used to create a base-64 encoded hash value (fixed length) of bitmap images (variable sized `state` input), but sadly I can't find it again.
3. The `action` lambda function that transforms `state` into the characters for the final string. The `Create()` method will call this function, passing the internal `Span<char>` it created for the string and your `state` data as the arguments.

For a very simple example, we can `Create()` a string from an array of characters like this:

```
char[] buffer = {'f', 'o', 'o'};
string result = string.Create(buffer.Length, buffer, (chars, buf) => {
    for (int i=0;i<chars.Length;i++) chars[i] = buf[i];
});
```

Of course, the basic `string(char[])` constructor would also work here, but that shows what a correct function might look like. Or we can map an array of ascii `int` values to a new string like this:

```
int[] buffer = {102, 111, 111};
string result = string.Create(buffer.Length, buffer, (chars, buf) => {
    for (int i=0;i<chars.Length;i++) chars[i] = (char)buf[i];
});
```

The function exists because there are some significant potential performance wins for this technique over traditional methods. For example, rather than reading a Stream into a buffer, you could pass the Stream object directly to `String.Create()` (assuming you know the final length). This avoids needing to allocate a separate buffer and avoids one round of copying values (stream=>buffer=>string becomes just stream=>string).

---

What happens when you call `string.Create()` is the function allocates a new string that already has the size determined by your `length` argument. This is one (and only one) heap allocation. Because `Create()` is a member of the string type, it has access to private string data for this new object you and I normally can't see. It now uses this access to create an internal `Span<char>` instance  pointed at the new string's internal character data.

This `Span<char>` lives on the stack, but acts on the heap memory from the new string... there is no additional allocation, and it's completely out of scope as soon as the `Create()` function returns, so everything is legal and safe. And because it's basically a pointer-with-benefits, there's virtually no risk of overflowing the stack unless you've done something else horribly wrong.

Now `Create()` calls your `action` function to do the heavy lifting of populating the string. Your `action` lambda can write into the `Span<char>`... for the duration of your lamdba's execution, strings are less-immutable than you may have heard!

When the `action` lamdba is finished, `Create()` can return the new, ready-to-use, string reference. Everything is good: we minimized heap allocations, preserved type safety and memory safety; the `Span<char>` is no longer accessible anywhere, and as a stack value is already destroyed. We also minimized unnecessary copying between buffers, depending on your `action` implementation.