# .NET Core 2.1 string.Create

Tags: c#, string, .net-core

I use `string.Create` method to create a new string like this:

```cs
var rawStr = "raw str";
var newStr = string.Create(rawStr.Length, rawStr,
                            (chars, str) =>
                            {
                                chars = str.ToCharArray();
                            });
```

but, the result **newStr** just an empty char array.

I saw an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54597722/example-of-how-to-use-string-create-in-net-core-2-1), and modify my code:

```cs
var rawStr = "raw str";
var newStr = string.Create(rawStr.Length, rawStr.ToCharArray(),
                            (chars, str) =>
                            {
                                //chars = str.ToCharArray();
                                for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
                                {
                                    chars[i] = str[i];
                                }
                            });
```

Then, **newStr**'s value is `raw str`, this is why?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to create a new string , which value equals **rawStr**'s value.

Comment: That seems like alot of overhead just to copy a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain what you are doing:

[String.Create documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.create?view=netcore-2.2)

> Creates a new string with a specific length and initializes it after creation by using the specified callback.

What you can achieve with the create, is a kind of conversion. In it's simplest form, it just takes an array of `chars` and creates as string.

Let's break down the function:

```
string.Create<TType>( newStrLength, typedOnject, creationFunction);
```

`TType` - It's the input type (in your case as string) that will be converted or used to create the new string

`newStrLength` - You need to provide the new string length

`typedOnject` - Object of type `TType` that will be given to the creation function

`creationFunction` - A lamda function that will do something based on the characters and the `TType` buffer. Create is calling this function. The chars are being provided by the Create and they are the new string's chars to modify as you please.

In your case, you creation function gets one by one the characters from the string and maps them to a new string, creating effectively a copy of one.

In your first attempt the following happens:

The chars array has a reference that is replaced by your new array that the ToCharArray returns. So by this assignment you are no longer referencing the characters that will be used to create the string. The original array remains unchanged.

In the second attempt you are changing the values of the original array and thus the new string uses it.

Comment: Thanks, what puzzling me is in the first piece of code, the **newStr**'s value is an empty char array, I dont's know where's wrong.

Comment: The chars array has a reference that is replaced by your new charArray. So by this assignment you are no longer referencing the characters that will be used to create the string. The original array remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in this complexity. Use this syntax:

```
var rawStr = "raw str";
var newStr = rawStr;
```